# How to tweak dired-create-empty-file to facilitate the easy creation of files

Tags: org-mode, dired, files, filenames

I currently have bound the command `dired-create-empty-file` to `f7`. Emacs then prompts me for a file name. When I press `f7` I would like Emacs to automatically create an ORG file and automatically generate a file name for it based on the date and time and then open the new file for editing. I find I prefer to rename files later if necessary than take the time to devise a name for them at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function and bind it to `F7` instead of binding dired-create-empty-file to it - something like this (lightly tested):

```
(defun my-dired-create-empty-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((ts (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%dT%H.%M.%S" (current-time)))
         (fname (format "%s.org" ts)))
    (dired-create-empty-file fname)
    (find-file fname)))
```

It probably does not handle the case of an existing file name properly, but if you wait at least one second between generating files, that should not be much of a problem :-).